# multiple records with A certificate in route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I have a custom domain setup in route53 and using rout53 as domain service provider. I have a static page hosted in aws s3 bucket which I am using as the home page of the site. In route53 I have mapped the aws s3 url to my custom domain by adding alias records as per this [document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html#root-domain-walkthrough-add-record-to-hostedzone).

I also have some lambda functions, which serves html pages on requests. Now I am trying to map the api endpoint of these lambda functions to my custom domain.

The flow is mainly like this, when the user hits the home website i.e. `xyz.com`, the homepage is served from the s3 static site. When the user navigates to other page say `xyz.com/products/productId`, the html is served from the lambda function. I am able to follow and do most of the steps for mapping api gateway endpoint to custom domain, but it's at adding DNS records I am facing the issue and getting the error `A record with specified name already exists`, which is understandable as I have already added the `A record` for routing to s3 bucket for my root domain.

My question is, can I add multiple records for the same type A in aws? Or is there other way to approach this problem?

Comment: DNS servers know nothing about URLs. HTTP servers and DNS servers operate at different layers of the OSI model. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do it this way. A DNS name can only resolve to one thing.

Instead, you could create a subdomain so that:

- `xyz.com` --> Amazon S3 bucket
- `products.xyz.com` --> API Gateway

You could pass the `productId` as a parameter (eg `products.xyz.com/?productId=42`).